# Getting assertion error when loading data into Redshift concurrently

Tags: java, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

We've recently switched to Redshift from Postgres for one of our java base app. The application is doing ETL(transforming source data into gzipped CSV, uploading to S3, and then using COPY to load the data into the table). The service is auto-scalable and therefore loading of the data can happen concurrently. Each concurrent chunk can import up to 16million records to the table. Sometimes, we're getting an assertion error from Redshift during COPY command execution:

```
Caused by: com.amazon.redshift.util.RedshiftException: ERROR: Assert
  Detail: 
  -----------------------------------------------
  error:  Assert
  code:      1000
  context:   shadow_logical_rows * Xen->cluster_manager->a_num_nodes(MyClusterVersion) == primary_logical_rows - shadow_logical_rows * Xen->cluster_manager->a_num_nodes(MyClusterVersion)=503, primary_logical_rows=511. 
  query:     0
  location:  small_table_utils.cpp:341
  process:   padbmaster [pid=19042]
  -----------------------------------------------
```

The copy command looks like:

```
copy table_name
from 's3://bucket/path_to_files'
iam_role 'redshift_role'
gzip
FORMAT CSV DELIMITER ',' IGNOREHEADER 1
```

Cluster consist of one dc2.large node.

**Important note**: there are usually multiple CSV files corresponding to s3 prefix specified in the copy

Having a hard time googling this error so appreciate any help

Comment: Does each COPY load multiple S3 files?  Are these files stable in S3 while the COPY executes?  An assert error is usually thrown when Redshift detects that something is wrong when running a query/statement/command.

Comment: If you have enterprise support, you may want to ask them. I had some good experience.